# Database-like files as targets and prerequisites in a Makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Say I have a simple Makefile.

```
a1: some_script b
    some_command $< b
a2: some_other_script b
    some_command $< b
b: c
    touch $@
c:
    touch $@
```

Where `b` is some database-like file that is required to make `a1` and `a2`. However, every time `b` is accessed (even if not altered) the modification date changes. Therefore, anytime the rule for `a2` is executed, Make thinks that `a1` needs to be remade because the database `b` was used (even if `c` hasn't changed and `b` remains the same). I only want to update `a1` and `a2` if `c` is newer (and therefore `b` is in need of actual re-compiling).

I could simply have `a1` and `a2` depend on c directly, but that misrepresents the true workflow.

I do not want to remove `b`, so having it as an intermediate file won't work.

I've also tried including `b` as an order-only dependency, but `a1` and `a2` will never be re-made unless forced to.

Notes: The Makefile is meant to automate executing scripts and keep track of dependencies for a research project (rather than a software project). Perhaps Make is not the right tool for this. The database-like files are GeoPackages.

Comment: How do you decide if `b` "_really_" changed? `md5sum`? Something else?

Comment: That's part of the problem, but in my case anytime `c` changes that would be sufficient to know that `b` and therefore `a1` and `a2` need to be remade. So I could have `a1` and `a2` just depend on `c` to achieve the desired result, even if it is not technically correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't rely on the timestamp of `b` to be accurate, then you need to not use it in your makefile.  You can do something like this:

```
a1: some_script .buildc
        some_command $< b

a2: some_other_script .buildc
        some_command $< b

.buildc: c
        command to update b
        touch $@

c:
        touch $@
```

This will run `command to update b` only if `c` is newer than `.buildc` which is set each time this command is invoked, not when `b` is used.

Comment: This is probably the best solution in my case. I now have a `.name.database` file associated with each database that acts as a Make timestamp for the actual database, which is also used as a prerequisite for other targets.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe just prevent useless changes of the timestamp of `b`:

```
a1: some_script b
    touch -r b .b.a1
    some_command $< b
    touch -r .b.a1 b && rm .b.a1

a2: some_other_script b
    touch -r b .b.a2
    some_command $< b
    touch -r .b.a2 b && rm .b.a2
```

But be careful: if you run make in parallel mode (`make -j`), `a1` and `a2` recipes could be run in parallel with potential race conditions. It is thus probably better to serialize them with `.NOTPARALLEL:` or by using `flock` in the recipes.

Comment: I chose the answer from @MadScientist as it was simpler to implement in my case  (as I would need to change the timestamp quite often using the above), but this would also be an adequate work around!

Answer (score 0):

I think the "[order-only prerequisite](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Prerequisite-Types.html)" might do the trick:

```
a1: some_script | b
    some_command $< b
a2: some_other_script | b
    some_command $< b
b: c
    touch $@
c:
    touch $@
```